# How to change AWS Support Plan on a member account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I log in with root credentials, I have the option to change the support plan in Support Center.

However, that only changes the Support Plan in the root account.

How do I do this for a member account in the organization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change support for a member account you log into that account using root credentials and enable support.